# fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects returning an NSCFString instead of NSArray

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to setup a UITableView with Core Data, using a fetchedResultsController.

The query itself appears ok.  I test it via an executeFetchRequest statement.

I call performFetch, with no error.

When I try to access fetchedObjects I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Looking at the returned variable in Xcode, it appears it's returning an _NSCFString instead of an NSArray.

I've searched all I could on Google, found many examples of this code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I can't seem to find an example of the same issue.

Below are the code sections:

.h file

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

NSFetchedResultsController *_fetchedResultsController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
 */
// Create the fetch request for the entity.

 NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Ingredient"];
 request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipe.name = %@",[self theRecipe].name];
 NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sequenceNumber" ascending:YES];
 request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *ingredients = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (!ingredients) {
    NSLog(@"** No Ingredients found");
} else if ([ingredients count] >= 0) {
    NSLog(@"**%d Ingredients found", [ingredients count]);
} 

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"myCache"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Inside ViewDidLoad

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

NSLog(@"fetchRequest = .... %@",[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest]);
NSLog(@"fetchedObjects = .... %@",[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects]);
NSLog(@"lastObject = .... %@",[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] lastObject]);
Ingredient *test = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] lastObject];
NSLog(@"test = %@", test.ingredient);
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects];  // EXC_BAD_ACCESS hit here
NSLog(@".... ingredients count = %@", [fetchedObjects count]);
```

Result from my executeFetchRequest inside fetchedResultsController method

```
2012-03-24 08:46:23.171 My App[103:707] **8 Ingredients found
```

Here is the Log output I get:

```
2012-03-24 08:46:23.186 My App[103:707] fetchRequest = .... <NSFetchRequest: 0x2c5180> (entity: Ingredient; predicate: (recipe.name == "Lasagne"); sortDescriptors: ((
"(sequenceNumber, ascending, compare:)"
)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

2012-03-24 08:46:23.192 My App[103:707] fetchedObjects = .... (
"<Ingredient: 0xee23e80> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee23100 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p9> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xee24120> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee23160 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p3> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xeed59a0> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee23170 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p7> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xeed5a00> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee23180 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xee243c0> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee23190 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p5> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xee24410> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee231a0 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xee24460> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee231b0 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p6> ; data: <fault>)",
"<Ingredient: 0xee244c0> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee231c0 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p8> ; data: <fault>)"
```

)

This shows 8 result records.  This is what I'm expecting.

```
2012-03-24 08:46:23.195 My App[103:707] lastObject = .... <Ingredient: 0xee244c0> (entity: Ingredient; id: 0xee231c0 <x-coredata://E3F4AFFB-B14F-4E94-80B1-F6101F92FAAD/Ingredient/p8> ; data: <fault>)

2012-03-24 08:46:23.198 My App[103:707] test = Salt
```

Again this is the value I'm expecting.

```
(gdb)
```

So why is the result of fetchedObjects not an NSArray, and how can I make it one?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is crashing on this line:

```
NSLog(@".... ingredients count = %@", [fetchedObjects count]);
```

`%@` points to an object. It needs to be `%i`.  `[fetchedObjects count]` returns an `NSUInteger` which is not an object. So the line should read:

```
NSLog(@".... ingredients count = %i", [fetchedObjects count]);
```

Look at this page: [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)